# String read from a stream is not added to the database

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate and it is working perfectly except for adding strings to the database
when I try to add string using this way

```
string charname = "Dan";
var account = new Account
{
    Username = charname
};
AccountRepository.Add(account);
```

it works but when I try to add the string that is read from a stream

```
string charname = reader.ReadString(false, length + 1);
 var account = new Account
 {
     Username = charname
 };
 AccountRepository.Add(account);
```

it adds nothing to the table. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

(Even though when printing the value charname it is printed correctly)

Comment: very descriptive title

Comment: When you debug the second version of the code and look at the contents of charname after the call to reader.ReadString, does charname  contain the string you are expecting?

Comment: that is why i am totally clueless

Comment: Any Idea ? i still trying with no luck

Comment: did you call `session.Flush();` or `transaction.Commit();` somwhere after the add? Did you get any Exceptions from database in the add, Flush or Commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a character appended to the value you want to add that the database is not accepting double check the value you are adding using debugging mode to check what is the actual value is before added to the databse.